# Where is a partial Blueprint.css appearance walkthrough?

Tags: css, user-interface, tabs, blueprint-css

A few days ago, I read a "first round of everything you need to know feature walkthrough" tutorial for Blueprint.css. This included, for instance, styling tabs, and what I'd need to make different tabs different colors using Blueprint, and so on and so forth. And I remember the initial walkthrough as being on the same page as an offering of "And if you really want to get down and dirty..."

I went to pull it again, and I haven't found the tutorial I remember, and search results all look like something else.

Where is (are) a standard, "gives the impression of being official" feature walkthrough for basic Blueprint.css usage that would make it clear how to style tabs for XYZ standard effects?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confused Boot*strap* and Blue*print*.

The documentation I wanted and needed is at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/.